# regex to extract values within parentheses and the word before parentheses using python

Tags: python

I would like to extract the values within parentheses and as well the word starting before it. For example, in a given text file, I would have the below details:

```
Total DB read time : TDBT(56) TDTO(78) TDTC(567) TON(567) TOT(345)
```

Expected output is a tuple or list:

```
TDBT 56 TDTO 78 TDTC 567 TON 567 TOT 345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split on `:` and replace the `()` with spaces using `str.translate`

```
s = "Total DB read time : TDBT(56) TDTO(78) TDTC(567) TON(567) TOT(345)"

spl = s.split(":")[1].translate({ord("("):" ",ord(")"):" "}).split()
['TDBT', '56', 'TDTO', '78', 'TDTC', '567', 'TON', '567', 'TOT', '345']
```

Or use `str.replace`:

```
s="Total DB read time : TDBT(56) TDTO(78) TDTC(567) TON(567) TOT(345)"

spl = s.split(":")[1].replace("("," ").replace(")"," ").split()
print(spl)
```

If you want pairs you can use re:

```
s="Total DB read time : TDBT(56) TDTO(78) TDTC(567) TON(567) TOT(345)"

import  re

r = re.compile("(\w+)\((\d+)\)")

print(r.findall(s))
[('TDBT', '56'), ('TDTO', '78'), ('TDTC', '567'), ('TON', '567'), ('TOT', '345')]
```